# Finding GCD, Socket Programming in Java

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have written the following two codes for finding GCD of two numbers. (via UDP Server)

**GCD_UDPClient.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class GCD_UDPClient 
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
        BufferedReader InFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        DatagramSocket ClientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        byte[] SendData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] ReceiveData = new byte[1024];

        System.out.print("First Number: ");
        String input1 = InFromUser.readLine();
        System.out.print("Second Number: ");
        String input2 = InFromUser.readLine();
        String Input = input1 + ' ' +input2;

        SendData = Input.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket SendPacket = new DatagramPacket(SendData, SendData.length, IPAddress, 9836);
        ClientSocket.send(SendPacket);
        DatagramPacket ReceivePacket = new DatagramPacket(ReceiveData, ReceiveData.length);
        ClientSocket.receive(ReceivePacket);
        String ModifiedInput = new String(ReceivePacket.getData());
        System.out.println("GCD From Server: " +ModifiedInput);
        ClientSocket.close();
   }
}
```

**GCD_UDPServer.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
class GCD_UDPServer 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        DatagramSocket ServerSocket = new DatagramSocket(9836);
        byte[] ReceiveData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] SendData = new byte[1024];
        while(true)
        {
            DatagramPacket ReceivePacket = new DatagramPacket(ReceiveData, ReceiveData.length);
            ServerSocket.receive(ReceivePacket);
            String input = new String(ReceivePacket.getData());
            InetAddress IPAddress = ReceivePacket.getAddress();
            int port = ReceivePacket.getPort();

            int ar[] = new int[2],i=0;
            for (String Number: input.split(" ", 2))
            {
                ar[i] = Integer.parseInt(Number);
                i=i+1;
            }
            String Answer = Integer.toString(calculategcd(ar[0],ar[1]));

            SendData = Answer.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket SendPacket = new DatagramPacket(SendData, SendData.length, IPAddress, port);
            ServerSocket.send(SendPacket);
        }
    }

    public static int calculategcd(int a, int b)
    {
        if(b%a == 0)
            return a;
        else 
            return calculategcd(b%a,a);
    }
}
```

`ClientSocket.receive(ReceivePacket);` doesn't seem to work properly, any clues why? Full codes are posted only for clarity.

Output given by the above codes:

```
First Number: 5
Second Number: 25
[waits indefinitely]
```

Output Required:

```
First Number: 5
Second Number: 25
GCD From Server: 5
```

Comment: Any error messages? What happens? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @GuntramBlohm >> Edited with `Output given by the above codes:` and `Output Required:`.

Comment: Did you check you have a bug in your code at
>>> ar[i] = Integer.parseInt(Number);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending 1024 bytes to the server, and you placed your data in a String like "5 25". When you receive the data you split it and you will have "5", and "25" followed by the other bytes in your buffer. Either you use `Number.trim()` to throw away those extra bytes, or you send a smaller packet (if that is possible).

Answer (score 1):

I had a test , the GCD_UDPServer.java have a exception like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at GCD_UDPServer.main(GCD_UDPServer.java:24)
```

and simply change line 24

```
ar[i] = Integer.parseInt(Number);
```

to

```
ar[i] = Integer.parseInt(Number.trim());
```

and it works properly.